# Getting unique numbers from two arrays

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, nsarray

If I have a couple of *NSArrays* filled with *ints*, or *NSNumbers*, like so:

```
A: { 12, 23, 45, 56, 67, 78, 99, 234 }
B: { 12, 56, 78, 99, 454, 512 }
```

How do I output an array with numbers that are in A but not in B, like

```
{ 23, 45, 67, 234 }
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

What you are tying to do is purely a set operation. So you can use *NSSet* here. You should do `minusSet:` to get the result you want.

```
NSMutableSet *resultSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:A];
NSSet *setB = [NSSet setWithArray:B];

// This is what you need!
[resultSet minusSet:setB];

Array *result = [resultSet allObjects];
```

Answer (score 2):

Create an NSMutableArray called C. Do a loop over A that tries to find each of its elements within B (using `[B containsObject:elemOfA]`, which just sends the `-isEqual:elemOfA` message to each member of B). If an element is found, do nothing; if an element isn't found, add it to C.